# Loosing data upon navigation, page change

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ngmodel

My app displays a `profile name` that can be edited. When i edit it it changes, great. When i navigate and come back, the data reset's.

I've tried holding the data (profile name) as a `String` variable, I've tried holding the data as a list and displaying the name with `String[0]` to display the unshifted profile name.

**First go**

```
<h3>{{profileService.profileName}}'s Profile</h3>

this.profileService.changeName(this.pName);

changeName(data){
    this.profileName = data;
}
```

**Second go**

```
<h3>{{profileService.profileNames[0]}}'s Profile</h3>

this.profileService.changeName(this.pName);

changeName(data){
    this.profileNames.unshift(data);
}
```

So, again, this updates initially when I go from edit-page to home-page. When I go to another page and return, the updated profile name is MISSING. Thanks!

Comment: would it be possible to create project on stackblitz.com/ and share a link? With that what is happening would be more clear.

Comment: I rebuilt it and it works now, but thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you made sure that:

- The service is provided for both the home page and the edit page?

This can be done by:
in app.module.ts (I guess you want your changes to persist for the whole application)

```
@NgModule({
  declarations:[
  //your components here
  ],
  imports:[
  //your modules here 
  ],
  providers:[
  ProfileService //and other services
  ]
})
```

or in profile.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'// which means there will be a single instance of the service in the whole application
})
export class ProfileService {
}
```

- The navigation between the home and edit page is using Angular Router: https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: thanks for the food for thought, these conditions were not the bug. I suppose they come with the build.